# pulling data from a multidimensional array json file downloaded from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am pulling data from an API, but when I do, it comes back in an array. I only need two of the items in the array.  Each of those items has 30 items and each of those has two entries.  With the code I have cobbled together through tutorials, I am able to pull out the Price and Volume, but each of those now have 30 items with two values each.  I only need the average of the second value.

[image: Array preview]

I need to pull the data in 0,0,1 though 0,30,1 and average them, as well as 2,0,1 through 2,30,1 and average those (highlighted values).

[image: highlighted values]

Eventually, I need to get to:
Price Average: X
Volume Average: Y

It has taken me all day just to get to this point, but I can't find a tutorial on how to pull data from a multidimensional array. **I am not asking for the code**, but where I can find what I need to learn it myself. Below, I am including the code I have written so far.  I think I am good so far (at least I get an output I expect), but I don't know where to learn the next step.

```js
const api_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=daily"
async function getEth() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const {
    prices,
    total_volumes
  } = data;
  document.getElementById('price').textContent = prices;
  document.getElementById('volume').textContent = total_volumes;
  console.log(prices);
  console.log(total_volumes)
}

getEth();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CG API</title>
</head>

<body>

  Prices: <span id="price"></span><br />
  </span><br /> Total Volumes: <span id="volume"></span></p>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can access the values the same way you would in a normal array.  Try to think of each array individually not as a multi dimensional array.  You may need to use a nested for loop, but they can be costly on big data sets.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Unlike an educational source, StackOverflow is actually _more_ about the code and the answer. Three are actually community rules that discourage asking for tutorials or other similar resources ([#3 here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). See also: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which could help you rewrite your question into an acceptable format. Be sure to include anything you've tried, and any errors you've received!

Comment: The syntax to access an element in a 2D array is `array[4][6]`. That gets the 4th array, then gets the 6th element from it.

Comment: Thank you at Chris.  So I need array[0][0][2], [0][1][2], etc. until [0][30][2]? For the first array at least.

Answer (score 0):

> For tutorial refer [this](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-reduce/) article for understanding how we can find total using reduce method.

**My code explanation:**

- You have data, all you need is to find the total sum of the total price and take an average of it.
- You calculate total of valid number values we can use `reduce()` method of an array.

```js
const totalPrice = prices.reduce((current, next) => {
    return current + next[1];
  }, 0)
```

- Above code is looping through each price's values and calculates the total of price. Here `current` parameter will start from 0[0 as you can see the last parameter we pass in reduce].
- Now your prices have arrays of two-element, for example `next=[1,2]` and as you need a sum of only the second value we can access the second value every time using next[1](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-reduce/), as the array is 0 based so the second item will on index 1.

```js
const api_url =
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=daily"
async function getEth() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const {
    prices,
    total_volumes
  } = data;
  // Calculating total of price
  const totalPrice = prices.reduce((current, next) => {
    return current + next[1];
  }, 0)
  // Calculating average of price
  const averagePrice = totalPrice / prices.length;
  // Calculating total of volume
  const totalVolumeSum = total_volumes.reduce((current, next) => {
    return current + next[1];
  }, 0)
  // Calculating average of volume
  const averageVolumesum = totalVolumeSum / total_volumes.length;

  document.getElementById('price').textContent = prices;
  document.getElementById('avgPrice').textContent = averagePrice;
  document.getElementById('volume').textContent = total_volumes;
  document.getElementById('avgVolume').textContent = averageVolumesum;

}

getEth();
```

```css
span {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CG API</title>
</head>

<body>

  Prices: <span id="price"></span><br /><br /> Average Price: <span id="avgPrice"></span><br />
  <br /> Total Volumes: <span id="volume"></span>
  <br /><br /> Average Volume: <span id="avgVolume"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Your description on pulling the second value makes sense now.  I'll read the tutorial.  Thank you for the code snippet too; I'll be able to use it as a comparison when I try to enter it myself.  And thank you for your patience (any reader) as I know I am not asking these questions in the ideal way.  It is hard learning to code after 50 :-), it is nice to interact with people who don't belittle you for trying something completely new.